# Like window (div) flashes and disappears

Tags: javascript, facebook-like, facebook-likebox

We have an identical [code for Like button (gist)](https://gist.github.com/df0765852d689963f08c) on 4 different pages. Sor some time, those pages were hidden behind basic HTTP auth, but now they are open.
There are different Facebook apps registered for each page.

On two of them, Like button works as expected. On two others, the Like "window" (div) appears for a fraction of second and disappears. Like is not saved. No errors appear in Javascript console.

All the apps have "August 2012 breaking changes" tick enabled.

How can I fix/debug this?

Comment: Did you try to debug the specific page with the facebook debug tool (http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug), that can give you great info. Make sure you're using all the necessary og and fb meta tags as explained here - http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=210086019031867 (this article is HIGHLY recommended)

Comment: Thanks, we do have one critical error. Will fix and report back.

Comment: Fixing that problem helped! We had a redirect loop on a page. You can actually make your commend an answer to gain some rep.